# Selecting Elements Within List with Square Function

Tags: r

I'm trying to get up to speed with lists in R and am trying to square every odd index position of each dataframe in a list. Please see the reproducible example below:

```
set.seed(100)
df <- data.frame(a = rnorm(5), b = rnorm(5))

oddsqr <- function(df){
  (df[seq(1, nrow(df), 2), 2])^2 #selects odd index positions from column 2
}
```

> How should I write my for loop in a way such that the squared value of every odd index position replaces the existing value? I've tried the solution below and it fails because I am trying to replace the existing rows in the data.frame with a length 3 vector instead of a length 5 vector.

```
for (i in seq_along(list.df)){
  list.df[[i]][[2]][i] <- oddsqr(list.df[[i]])
}
```

**Solution**

Based on the example above, I've figured out how to get the answer but it looks terribly unreadable. Would appreciate it if anyone can help me optimize it:

```
for (k in seq_along(list.df)){
  for (i in seq_along(list.df)){
      list.df[[k]][[2]][vec[i]] <- oddsqr(list.df[[k]])[i]
  }
}
```

**Solution 2**

Based on Markus's solution below: lapply can be used in this case to make everything cleaner and faster!

Comment: @markus if i dont put them in such a manner, I will not be able to get the answer though!

Comment: You are absolutely right about it. My bad. Ignore my comment above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider `lapply`

```
out <- lapply(list.df, function(x) {
  idx <- seq(1, nrow(x), 2)
  x[idx, 2] <- x[idx, 2] ^ 2
  x
})
```

Result

```
out
#$df1
#  a  b
#1 1  1
#2 2  2
#3 3  9
#4 4  4
#5 5 25

#$df2
#  a  b
#1 1  1
#2 2  2
#3 3  9
#4 4  4
#5 5 25
```

---

Using a `for`-loop with a slight modification of OP's function we can get the same result

```
# returns modified dataframe now and not a vector
oddsqr <- function(df){
  df[seq(1, nrow(df), 2), 2] <- df[seq(1, nrow(df), 2), 2]^2 #selects odd index positions from column 2
  df
}

for (i in seq_along(list.df)) {
  list.df[[i]] <- oddsqr(list.df[[i]])
}
list.df
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 1:5)
list.df <- list(df1 = df, df2 = df)
```

Comment: thanks for helping out! Do you happen to know to do it using a function method? The reason being is that I'm trying out the function method without lappy

Comment: @Javier Updated my answer. Let me know if something is unclear.

Comment: thanks for helping! it works perfectly and i'm beginning to understand list better

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation in `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
map(list.df, ~ .x %>%
                mutate(b = case_when(row_number() %% 2 == 1 ~ b^2,
                                     TRUE ~ as.numeric(b))))
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 1:5)
list.df <- list(df1 = df, df2 = df)
```